# How can I make OS X recognize drive letters?

Tags: java, macos, filesystems

I know.  Heresy.  But I'm in a bind.  I have a lot of config files that use absolute path names, which creates an incompatibility between OS X and Windows.  If I can get OS X (which I'm betting is the more flexible of the two) to recognize *Q:/foo/bar/bim.properties* as a valid absolute file name, it'll save me *days* of work spelunking through stack traces and config files.

In the end, I need this bit of Java test code to print "SUCCESS!" when it runs:

```
import java.io.*;

class DriveLetterTest {
    static public void main(String... args) {
        File f = new File("S:");
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("FAIL!");
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know how this can be done?

UPDATE:  Thanks for all the feedback, everyone.  It's now obvious to me I really should have been clearer in my question.

Both the config files and the code that uses them belong to a third-party package I cannot change.  (Well, I *can* change them, but that means incurring an ongoing maintenance load, which I want to avoid if at all possible.)

I'm in *complete* agreement with all of you who are appalled by this state of affairs.  But the fact remains: I can't change the third-party code, and I really want to avoid forking the config files.

Comment: I'm guessing this can't be done, but it is an interesting question.

Comment: My question would be, what would Q translate to on the Mac system, and can you differentiate whether the app is running on Windows or Mac and translate it at that point?

Comment: I want to map Q: to something like ~/workspace.  

Unfortunately, references to "Q:/..." are scattered like confetti throughout dozens of config files, and are used by code I don't control.  So the only means of translating the file path for use on OS X is to force-feed the JVM an alternate java.io.File implementation.

Comment: no it isn't, look at my answer for an alternate solution at runtime

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258762/how-can-i-make-os-x-recognize-drive-letters

Comment: Responding to your comments on several answers: Surely this third-party package has config files *to allow you to change them*, so actually changing them for OSX *is not* forking the package. At worst, you could make it part of your OSX install to do a `find xxx | sed xxx` to modify the "unforked" files at install time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you'd have to provide a different `java.io.File` implementation that can parse out the file paths correctly, maybe there's one someone already made.
The real solution is to put this kind of stuff (hard-coded file paths) in configuration files and not in the source code.

Comment: Alas, the hard-coded paths are already in config files.  Lots of them.  And these same config files have to be used on both OS X and Windows.  So I have to either write a script that does a find & replace on all those paths, tweak OS X to recognize drive letters and let me map them to arbitrary directories, or (as you suggest) provide the JVM itself with an alternate java.io.File implementation.

Comment: I agree. You should have such fix coded paths in your application. Avoid them by relative-paths, using wll defined directories or putting the paths into configuration files.

Comment: Are you willing to provide a new File implementation but not change your text config files? :-/

Comment: I think you should change your config files.

Comment: The config files are part of a third-party package I don't control.  I *could* modify them, but that would mean essentially forking that package, and accepting the maintenance burden of keeping my configs in sync with the trunk line.

In this case, I'm willing to consider tweaking java.io.File because it imposes very little ongoing maintenance load.  It's a hack, but it's a little one that only affects me, and only when I upgrade my JVM.  Trying to modify the parsing code or config files means daily headaches every time someone else on the team adds new config properties/changes.

Comment: or  instead of providing an alternate File implementation, if you have access to the source just make a wrapper object that does the translation for you and put it in place of 'File'.

Answer (score 3):

**Honestly**, don't hard-code absolute paths in a program, even for a single-platform app. Do the correct thing.

The following is my wrong solution, saved to remind myself not to repeat giving a misdirected advice ... shame on me.

<strike>Just create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) named `Q:` just at the root directory `/` to `/` itself.</strike>

```
$ cd /
$ ln -s / Q:
$ ln -s / S:
```

You might need to use `sudo`. Then, at the start of your program, just `chdir` to `/`.

If you don't want `Q:` and `S:` to show up in the Finder, perform

```
$ /Developer/Tools/SetFile -P -a V Q:
$ /Developer/Tools/SetFile -P -a V S:
```

which set the invisible-to-the-Finder bit of the files.

Comment: I would be pissed if I installed some software that littered my filesystem with symlinks like this!

Comment: I know, I know ... :p But I just provided the OP the simplest of all solutions! OK I added extra instructions to hide files from Finder :p

Comment: bad advice is worse than no advice, this isn't simple it is a worst practice anti-pattern hack in the worst way, shame on you for even suggesting it

Comment: If OP can't use different config files per OS, I think it would be harder to create symbolic links.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** No.
**Long answer:** For Java you should use `System.getProperties(XXX)`.
Then you can load a Properties file or Configuration based on what you find in `os.name`.
**Alternate Solution** just strip off the `S:` when you read the existing configuration files on non-Windows machines and replace them with the appropriate things.
**Opinion:** Personally I would bite the bullet and deal with the technical debt now, fix all the configuration files at build time when the deployment for OSX is built and be done with it.

```
public class WhichOS
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        System.out.format("System.getProperty(\"os.name\") = %s\n", System.getProperty("os.name"));
        System.out.format("System.getProperty(\"os.arch\") = %s\n", System.getProperty("os.arch"));
        System.out.format("System.getProperty(\"os.version\") = %s\n", System.getProperty("os.version"));
    }
}
```

the output on my iMac is:

```
System.getProperty("os.name") = Mac OS X
System.getProperty("os.arch") = x86_64
System.getProperty("os.version") = 10.6.4
```

Comment: I think in this case the "Long answer" is the "Sane answer" - use different configurations for a different OS.

Comment: I totally agree with everything you've said.  My own code is built without hard-coded file names, doesn't care what OS it's running on, where in the filesystem it lives, etc.

Alas, the code that parses the paths is third-party code I can't touch.  And the config files have to work on both OS X and Windows.  So the only options I have left are tweaking OS X to effectively symlink drive letters to dirs, or tweak the java.io.File implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested something out, and discovered something interesting: In Windows, if the current directory is on the same logical volume (i.e. root is the same drive letter), you can leave off the drive letter when using a path. So you could just trim off all those drive letters and colons and you should be fine as long as you aren't using paths to items on different disks.

Comment: Good approach ... configuring a system across multiple drives is sometimes unavoidable, but even then it's possible using symlinks to unify the result as a single filesystem tree.  Requiring drive letters paths is an anti-pattern, imo

Answer (score 2):

If you are not willing to change your config file per OS, what are they for in first place?

Every installation should have its own set of config files and use it accordingly.

But if you insist.. you just have to detect the OS version and if is not Windows, ignore the letter:

Something along the lines:

```
boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase()
        .contains("windows");

String folder = "S:";
if (isWindows && folder.matches("\\w:")) {
    folder = "/";
} else if (isWindows && folder.matches("\\w:.+")) {
    folder = folder.substring(2);// ignoring the first two letters S:
}
```

You get the idea

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can replace java.io.File is to replace that class in rt.jar.

I don't recommend that, but the best way to do this is to grab a bsd-port of the [OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/bsd-port/bsd-port/) code, make necessary changes, build it and redistribute the binary with your project. Write a shell script to use your own java binary and not the built-in one.

PS. Just change your config files! Practice your regex skills and save yourself a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I finally ended up doing:

I downloaded the source code for the java.io package, and tweaked the code for java.io.File to look for path names that start with a letter and a colon. If it finds one, it prepends "/Volumes/" to the path name, coughs a warning into System.err, then continues as normal.

I've added symlinks under /Volumes to the "drives" I need mapped, so I have:

- /Volumes/S:
- /Volumes/Q:

I put it into its own jar, and put that jar at the front of the classpath for *this project only*.  This way, the hack affects only me, and only this project.

Net result: java.io.File sees a path like "S:/bling.properties", and then checks the OS.  If the OS is OS X, it prepends "/Volumes/", and looks for a file in /Volumes/S:/bling.properties, which is fine, because it can just follow the symlink.

Yeah, it's ugly as hell.  But it gets the job done for today.

Comment: haha, you're welcome :-).  Glad to hear it worked, I've never done something like that!

Comment: Ah, I should post an addendum here.  I had to put the symlinks under ~/Drives/, since OS X kept cleaning them out of /Volumes.

Comment: it might be slightly less awful if you avoided the global symlinks and used a user directory.  Like when you said you wanted "~/workspace".

Comment: Gary, you're quite right.  See my addendum above, where I note that I put them under ~/Drives.